# Can't add 1 to a user-variable in SQL incrementally

Tags: php, mysql

It's possibly due to the variable `@count` not being recognised as an integer but in my research I've come across many example similar to `@count = @count + 1`; That's why I'm confused as to why this breaks my code when introduced:

```
$setCount = "SELECT @count:=5";
$uncategorise = "UPDATE pictures
    SET category = '0',
    pictureorder = @count,
    @count:=@count+1
    WHERE category = '$categoryID'
    AND username = '$username';
$queryCount = mysql_query($setCount) or die(mysql_error());
$queryUncat = mysql_query($uncategorise) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because this is an [user defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html),
which only stand/available for the same session/connection

> You can store a value in a user-defined variable in one statement and then refer to it later in another statement. This enables you to pass values from one statement to another. User-defined variables are **connection-specific**. That is, a user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. All variables for a given client connection are automatically freed when that client exits.

There is an easy solution -- [php mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Ah. What threw me was that I could refer to it fine, leading me to believe it hadn't gone away and, therefore, could be added to. Thankyou!

Comment: `mysql_query` is fairly deeply woven into the rest of the site so (on first glance) it looks like implementing `mysqli_multi_query` mightn't be as straightforward as I hoped.

Comment: alternative you can use store procedure

Comment: I may have found a way to use an existing factor of each row as an increment and avoid complicating the query. Thanks very much for showing two possibilities. I'll give them a go should this new approach not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a field in the DB that does the counting and then retrieve the data from there.

Comment: Would that not be a doable, but more complex solution if I can recreate the above with one query? Perhaps this isn't doable inside PHP with a single query. I'm trying to keep the query as inexpensive as possible.